# nextjs error with react router when trying to redirect

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm facing the following error when using useRouter hook by nextjs.

TypeError: url.startsWith is not a function

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter()

function onAppointmentConfirmed() {    
    const fakeData = '12321'

    router.push({
      pathname: '/appointment/success',
      query: {
        data: fakeData,
      },
    })
  }
```

I have a button that triggers this function in order to redirect but I need to pass some data to the next screen (eg fakeData). This -> router.push('/appointment/success') works but I cannot carry any data onto the next screen.

edit :

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


export default function index() {
const router = useRouter()

const handleClick = () => {
 router.push({
   pathname: '/',
   query: {
     data: 'data',
   },
 })
}

return <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Click me to redirect</button>
}
```

Comment: Where is `router` declared? Where are you using a `useRouter` hook? Can you update your question to include all relevant code?

Comment: I have edited my OP. I do no think that is the issue. As I mention, router.push('/appointment/success') works just fine. All I need is to pass some data along with the redirect

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a valid React hook use. Hooks can only be called within React functions or other React hooks. Can you also share how you are attempting to receive the passed data on the receiving end?

Comment: This is only a small part of the code as I cannot publish the whole component. I am calling the hook inside an React function, nothing is breaking. I'm telling you for the 3rd time already that router.push('/appointment/success') is working properly

Comment: I've not said anything about `router.push('/appointment/success')` working or not, just probing for a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without valid, runnable code it's difficult to say why your code isn't working as expected. I don't see any issue specifically with the way you've passed an object with `pathname` and `query` properties. So that is why I asked what level of debugging have you done to see what is passed through. Saying something "isn't working" isn't helpful for anyone.

Comment: Edited the post again, that recreates the problem in my repo as well

Comment: @SteliosK The second code block is fine, and doesn't trigger any error. Can you please show the full code where you use `onAppointmentConfirmed`?

Comment: I made a new page on my nextjs project and Im only using the second block of code as it is. I'm getting the same error